# Helicity of muons in muon production

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams

Page 150 of Larkoski Particle Physics says that

$$v_L(k_2) = i\sqrt{E_{cm}} \begin{bmatrix}-\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}) \\ \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})\end{bmatrix}$$

for an outgoing left helicity muon in electron muon scattering. However, on page 147 it says that $v_L(p) = u_R(p)$, and that
$$u_R(p) = \sqrt{2E} \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}) \\ \sin(\frac{\theta}{2})\end{bmatrix}$$ (with a factor of $e^{i\phi}$ in the front).

My question is, if $v_L(k_2) = u_R(p)$, then how can the first entry of the spinors have different trig functions? I’m thinking that it might be because $k$ and $p$ are different vectors, since

$$p =E(1, \sin(\theta)cos(\phi), \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), \cos(\theta))$$

and

$$k_2 =E(1, -\sin{\theta}, 0, -\cos{\theta})$$

But even when you consider this there’s no reason for flipping the entries. Why are the trig functions swapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries are not "flipped", the angle $\theta$ is simply defined differently for your two vectors.

Writing the two vectors as functions of the angles $p(\theta, \phi)$ and $k(\theta)$, you have $p(\theta + \pi,0) = k(\theta)$, since $\sin(x+\pi) = -\sin(x)$ and likewise for $\cos$. Using $\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \cos(x)$ then shows $u_R(p(\theta,0)) = v_L(k(\theta +\pi))$, as your text claims.