# Where does the $i$ come from in the left helicity antimuon spinor?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, conventions, scattering, feynman-diagrams, spinors

Context: this appears in $e^{+}e^{-} \rightarrow \mu^{+}\mu^{-}$ scattering.

Page 247 of Larkoski particle physics says $$v_L(p) = \sqrt{2E}(e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}}\cos(\frac{\theta}{2}), e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})).$$

It then says that $$v_L(k_2) = i\sqrt{E_{cm}}(-\sin(\frac{\theta}{2}), \cos(\frac{\theta}{2})).$$

I’m trying to arrive from $v_L(p)$ to $v_L(k_2)$ by substituting $\theta \rightarrow \theta + \pi$ and $\phi$ = 0, but if $\phi$ = 0, what’s the reason that there’s an $i$ in the front of the $\sqrt{E_{cm}}$ ?

I chose $\phi$ = 0 because in this answer (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/734463/310742) by CuriousMind, it’s said that $\phi$ = 0.

In short, wouldn’t $\phi = 0$ force the outgoing anti-muon spinor to be real?

Comment: I don’t have a copy of Larkoski. In the linked question, you say that $v_L(p)$ has a factor of $e^{i\phi}$ in front that you didn’t show. In this question you show the two terms with factors of $e^{-i\phi/2}$ and $e^{i\phi/2}$. Which is it?

Comment: @Ghoster I didn’t mean an overall factor in front. I meant what I showed in this question. Sorry.

Comment: Phases are not observable, the factor of $i$ can be reabsorbed into the definition of one-particle states. It seems the book might have used inconsistent definitions. Not a big deal anyway -- pick whatever convention you like and stick with it. Perhaps find a better book if you want someone to choose a consistent set of conventions for you.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform yeah the book is not that great with derivations, but I like their explanations. So if the factor of “i” doesn’t really matter, then the squared value of the matrix element should still give us the same result, right?

Comment: @Obama2020 It is not the square of the matrix element, it is the *absolute value* of the square, $P=|\mathcal A|^2$. Any global phase in $\mathcal A$ makes no difference (but you have to use a consistent convention: if $\mathcal A$ has multiple terms, you cannot use $v$ in one of them and $iv$ in another, since the $i$ will not factorize and become a global phase, it will instead cause interference!).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform yes that’s what I meant

Comment: I will do the calculation sometime later and come back if I have any more questions

Comment: Yep, math checks out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to be fully rigurous, let's keep $\phi$ generic, in which case
$$ k_1 = \frac{E_{CM}}{2} (1, \sin \theta \cos \phi, \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta ) \ \ \ \ \ \  k_2 = \frac{E_{CM}}{2} (1, - \sin \theta \cos \phi, - \sin \theta \sin \phi, - \cos \theta ) $$

So that $k_2$ has angles $\theta' = \pi - \theta$ and $\phi' = \phi + \pi$

The expression of the spinor using your book's convention is then

$$ v_L(k_2) = \sqrt{E_{CM}} (\mathrm{e}^{-i \frac{\phi}{2}} \mathrm{e}^{-i \frac{\pi}{2}} \sin \frac{\theta}{2}, \mathrm{e}^{i \frac{\phi}{2}}\mathrm{e}^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} \cos \frac{\theta}{2}) $$

Now we can either let $\phi$ be arbitrary, and remark that the modulus of the matrix element squared doesn't depend on it, or choose a particular direction since we have cylindrical symmetry.

If we choose $\phi = 0$, by remarking $\mathrm{e}^{\pm i \frac{\pi}{2}} = \pm i$, we get
$$ v_L(k_2) = \sqrt{E_{CM}} (-i  \sin \frac{\theta}{2}, i \cos \frac{\theta}{2}) $$

So the factor $i$ comes from the fact that $\phi\to \phi + \pi$ for $k_2$. Note that $\theta \to \theta + \pi$ is not acceptable since $\theta$ should stay between $0$ and $\pi$. The true transformation from $k_1$ to $k_2$ is $\theta \to \pi - \theta$, $\phi \to \phi + \pi$